# What does "paperback rights" mean?

Tags: copyright

Say an author sells the paperback rights of a book for $300,000

What does that mean? The author gets $300,000 and then nothing else, even if the book sells five hundred million copies?

Comment: Context would be helpful. "Paperback rights" is a colloquial phrase usually used in the popular press and during informal oral negotiations in advance of a written licensing agreement which would define the terms more precisely. It would usually be used in a context when most terms of the agreement are implied by customary practice. The meaning is not necessarily uniform in all contexts and you would need to look at how the source used the term over time in previous descriptions to know what that speaker or writer means.

Answer (score 2):

Books are published in several different formats. Traditionally the hardback edition came first, followed by the paperback edition some time later and probably from a different customer. Hardbacks sell at a premium, so you could charge more, and also get more money from impatient readers who couldn't bear to wait for the paperback.

Cheaper novels would go straight to paperback. There was also the "trade paperback" format, which meant the size of a hardback but with card covers rather than hardback. Now we also have electronic editions.

Typically an author will cut a deal with a publisher for the rights to a book. Usually these are for a particular market (e.g. "US hardback") and will have various exclusivity and timing built in to them. The details depend on negotiations between publisher and author (or more usually the author's agent).

The rights sold to a publisher are a license to print copies under certain conditions. It is not (usually) the whole copyright. An author will want to sell different rights to different people, including movie rights and audiobook rights. Doing it this way gets more money for the author (and every author dreams of the big film deal).

The two big numbers are the advance and the royalties. For instance a book may be sold for a $10,000 advance and a royalty of $2/copy. The advance is paid to the author up-front and is not refundable; in our example if the book sells less than 5,000 copies then the publisher is out of money. Once the advance has been "earned out" in book sales then the author starts getting more money. So in our example the author gets $10,000 up front, and then on sale 5,001 the author gets an extra $2, and again for each copy sold after that.

"*Paperback rights sold for $300,000*" probably means that the author has been paid a $300,000 advance for a book that is going straight to paperback.

For more information you might like to read [these essays](https://www.antipope.org/charlie/blog-static/2010/04/common-misconceptions-about-pu-1.html) by Charles Stross, who gives an author's-eye view of the whole publishing world.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't legally mean anything. If you read the agreement, it probably says something entirely different, and "paperback rights" is just popular jargon. The agreement is presumably not a transfer of copyright if it is restricted to paperback editions. You would have to read the license agreement and see what it actually says, but from what you propose, the publishers "consideration" is a lump sum with no royalties. It's a gamble: the author really wins if the book only sells 100 copies, and really loses if it sells 1,000,000,000 copies. The author can negotiate with the publisher.

Comment: That’s not normally how publishing contracts work. Typically, the author’s payment is an advance on royalties (so if their royalties end up being more than the advance, they start getting royalty checks).